# After installing phabricator when I logged in the Blank page appears

Tags: php, mysql, apache, phabricator

I have succefully installed phabricator on ubuntu but when I registered the admin user blank page appears. Even I tried to recover the user using ./bin/auth recover user but it did not work. It just shows the login page and then white blank page. Even I have to clear the browser cache to see the login page again. Please help.

Comment: Have you debug what error did you find on your server side? (e.g using PHP, ini_set('display_errors', 1);

Comment: where to put this line??

Comment: Try place it on top on your phabricator's index page

Comment: @Atul Agrawal explore php logs

Comment: i posted this question on phabricator home page and they said because php-gd is missing and hence it show me this error.@Javed Ahmed please try the same

Comment: Is there anything in the error logs? /var/log/apache2/error_log

Answer (score 2):

I will assume your project name is my_project:

```
   - sudo apt-get php-gd php-curl php-apc php-cli php-mbstring –y    

   - sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/my_project

   - sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem, it was finally solved by installing this package

> sudo apt-get install php7.1-gd

I had previously installed

> sudo apt-get install php7.1 php7.1-mbstring php7.1-curl php7.1-mysql

Note - I am running php7.1 on Linux Mint 18.1 by following the instructions here
https://www.vultr.com/docs/how-to-install-and-configure-php-70-or-php-71-on-ubuntu-16-04
As Phabricator does not work on php7.0 which is the default in ubuntu 16.04 / Linux Mint 18.1.

Similar packages will exist for other versions of PHP.